# maven test dependencies of dependencies

Tags: maven, dependencies, testng

I have a large project and i want to add an integration tests module which will depend on every thing and validate interaction between modules.

The issue is that during the test I'm missing the dependency classes
module A uses module B
I have a test on **module A** testing something that uses **module B**, and I'm getting an error stating it can't find classes in module B.

I tried surefire but there is no difference.

I know I can and I should mock the classes in B which aren't part of the test but I want a full test that will test everything.

Comment: This is not clear to me. If you have a dependency which itself has a dependency of scope `test`, then this second dependency will be missing. This is the intended behaviour.

Comment: I know and i want to change this behavior, can I?
module A depend on module B in default compile scope

Answer (score 0):

As official `Maven` [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) declares `test` scope is not transitive. You need to declare required dependencies explicitly in the `pom` file(s).

Comment: module A depend on module B in default compile scope, i just use module A in test the dependencies are in compile scope

Comment: If I understand you correctly you should use `test` scope for module `A`. `B` dependency will be fetched.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change this behaviour, but there is usually no need to change this behaviour.

If you want to write a library that is used for testing, then this library should have `compile` dependencies, but when you use it, declare it with scope `test`.